# Encoding type error while using SentimentIntensityAnalyzer

Tags: python, pandas

I get the error when I run the code below

TypeError: 'encoding' is an invalid keyword argument for this function.

I'm not sure if I have the datatype for each value has to be something else. It is a string so it should work.

```
df = pd.read_csv('df.csv')

def get_sentiment(row):
    body = row['body']
    analyzer = SentimentIntensityAnalyzer()
    scores = analyzer.polarity_scores(body)
    return scores['compound']

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    get_sentiment(row)
```

Comment: Seems to me this error shows up in `python2` with some modules . Try using `python3` instead

Comment: @RafaelC i get this error when i use python3: "UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xed in position 10: invalid continuation byte"